# TableLayout dinamico de manera programatica

Tags: android-studio, android-layout

Pretendo rellenar un tablelayout con botones indicándole el numero de filas y de columnas. La cosa es que por alguna razón no me pilla de manera programática la altura y la anchura del tablerow.

Adjunto método para rellenar el tablelayout:

```
public void crearTableLayout(int numeroFilas, int numeroColumnas){
        tableLayout.removeAllViews();
        for (int i = 0;i <numeroFilas;i++){//8 veces
            TableRow fila = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());//Instanciamos
            //Declaramos atributos de la fila
            TableRow.LayoutParams lpFila = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            lpFila.weight=1;//Peso
            fila.setLayoutParams(lpFila);//Los añadimos a la fila
            //Agregamos elementos a la tabla
            for (int y = 0; y < numeroColumnas; y++){
                Button boton = new Button(getApplicationContext());//Instanciamos
                boton.setId(View.generateViewId());
                TableRow.LayoutParams lpButton = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);//Parametros del layout para el boton
                lpButton.weight=1;
                boton.setLayoutParams(lpButton);//Añadimos los parametros al boton
                fila.addView(boton);//Añadimos el boton a la fila
            }
            //Agregamos la fila a el tablelayout
            tableLayout.addView(fila);
        }
    }
```

He probado a hacer un ejemplo con esos atributos desde xml directamente y si que lo rellena correctamente, el ejemplo en xml seria este:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" />

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/my_toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button118"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
```

Adjunto imagen de como me queda de manera programática y donde se observa que la anchura la pilla bien, pero la altura del tablelayout no la rellena.

[image: Lo que recibes]

Pd: El tablelayout en el diseño xml esta inicialmente sin filas y en el ejemplo es un 8x8; esta instanciado de la siguiente manera en el main.java:

```
TableLayout tableLayout;
tableLayout = findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);
```

Resultado esperado (conseguido mediante el ejemplo de xml):

[image: Lo que pides]

Answer (score 1):

Adjunto la solución a mi pregunta.
En mi caso era un error a la hora de implementar los parametros del layout del tablerow; deben de ser los del elemento padre, tablelayout.params en vez de tablerow.params.

```
TableLayout.LayoutParams lpFila = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);//Parametros del layout para el boton
            lpFila.weight=1;//Peso
            fila.setLayoutParams(lpFila);//Los añadimos a la fila
```

Es una tontería, pero en mi caso he perdido horas por esa cosilla, así que dejo la solución por si las moscas.

```
public void crearTableLayout(int numeroFilas, int numeroColumnas){
        tableLayout.removeAllViews();
        for (int i = 0;i <numeroFilas;i++){//8 veces
            TableRow fila = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());//Instanciamos
            //Declaramos atributos de la fila
            TableLayout.LayoutParams lpFila = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);//Parametros del layout para el boton
            lpFila.weight=1;//Peso
            fila.setLayoutParams(lpFila);//Los añadimos a la fila
            //Agregamos elementos a la tabla
            for (int y = 0; y < numeroColumnas; y++){
                Button boton = new Button(getApplicationContext());//Instanciamos
                boton.setId(View.generateViewId());
                TableRow.LayoutParams lpButton = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);//Parametros del layout para el boton
                lpButton.weight=1;
                boton.setLayoutParams(lpButton);//Añadimos los parametros al boton
                fila.addView(boton);//Añadimos el boton a la fila
            }
            //Agregamos la fila a el tablelayout
            tableLayout.addView(fila);
        }
    }
```